# Regenerating an entity using EF 6.1 DataBase First without losing Enum Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, enums

I'm having a difficult time trying to understand:
1) How to add an Enum Type to an Entity
2) How to convert an existing property type in an Entity to an Enum.

I've read several docs, tried some things but none seem clear...

I went to the Model Browser to add a new Enum type and added this field to my entity. First off, is this the correct way of doing it? Secondly, if I regenerate the entity, I will lose my Enum type. Can this be prevented?

Secondly, how can I convert an existing property in an entity to an Enum type?

I like doing DataBase First, because when using WCF, I can edit the edmx template for attributes needed for namespaces and WCF specific items.

I can use a buddy class for the data validation against my ViewModels as opposed to Code First where it automatically creates the assumed DataAnnotations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) With database first you cannot do this, only code first.  Most people use a T4 script to create an Enum class based on these lookup tables.

2) Can't, again, code first only.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly when this changed, but you **can** do this database first, now.  When creating the Enum in your model browser, check the option to reference an external enum, then enter the full name.